# What did Blanche do that was "dumb"?

Tags: plot-explanation, bonnie-and-clyde

About an hour into *Bonnie and Clyde*,  the newly enlarged gang makes a narrow escape after the cops show up at their rented cottage.

In the car,  after their getaway, Bonnie (Faye Dunaway) yells at Blanche, who's screaming hysterically, "You almost got us killed!"  Blanche cries, "What did I do wrong? " Buck then says to Blanche,  "You shouldn't have done that Blanche.  It was a dumb thing to do."

Now, it was the ordering of groceries that actually got them discovered (apparently) and it seemed Bonnie took care of that. And Clyde starts shooting before the gang even knows if the cops are there for them. So the actual predicament is perhaps more their fault.

Blanche did yell and scream when the cops arrived,  and get separated from the gang at one point,  but was there really **a** thing that Blanche did that was to blame for the near capture?

Comment: They are criminals and murderers.  Unfairly blaming someone for their problems doesn't seem out of character to me.

Comment: I agree it's not out of character, but there seemed to be a specific reason, and Blanche didn't challenge except for initially (and *that's* not out of character either)

Comment: I remember thinking the same thing, and I believe what that is was part of director Penn's target of making Blanche the establishment figure, not embraced by (for lack of a better phrase) "the cool kids". Blanche was a bad-ass IRL but she was remade into a mewling preacher's daughter to make Bonnie more cool. This seemed like one of the movie's many attempts to square her up.